# Forbid assigning a variable of type any to a variable of other type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

So I have this piece of code

```
let var1: any;
var1 = 'hello';
let var2: number = var1;
```

For some reason typescript is NOT complaining that I am trying to assign a variable of type `any` to a `number`. Does anybody know is there is a compiler or tslint rule that forbids this?. Yes I now I can disallow `any`, but even if it is disallowed the error would happen in `line 1`, not in `line 3`.

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20var1%3A%20any%3B%0D%0Avar1%20%3D%20'hello'%3B%0D%0Alet%20var2%3A%20number%20%3D%20var1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20StateParams%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunc(theVar%3A%20StateParams)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20I%20know%20myParam%20is%20a%20number%2C%20but%20all%20typescript%20knows%20is%20that%20myParam%20is%20of%20type%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20otherVar%3A%20number%20%3D%20theVar.myParam%3B%0D%0A%7D)

---

*Adding more detail to my original question*

My specific case is when using a third-party library that has a definition like

```
// Definition file
export declare class StateParams {
    [key: string]: any;
}

... later on in my own code

function myFunc(theVar: StateParams) {
    // I know myParam is a number, but all typescript knows is that myParam is of type any
    let otherVar: number = theVar.myParam;
}
```

So, even if I have the tsLint `no-any` rule, this won't help and typescript won't complain, and I can't do anything about `StateParams` as I can't control it

Comment: TSLint rule is `no-any`. The rest is what the answer says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the TypeScript language specification under the section "3.11.4 Assignment Compatibility" (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.11.4):

> S is assignable to a type T, and T is assignable from S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T (3.11.5) and one of the following is true:
>
> - S and T are identical types.
> - S or T is the Any type.

This indicates that any type is assignable to "any" and "any" is assignable to any other type.

The best practice is to never use type "any" in your code unless you are moving an existing JS code base to TS. In that case, you can start with "any" for all types and over time change them to more specific types.

In case your variable has a complex type that cannot be captured with simple TS types, you can either manually define a more specific type or use unions to allow for multiple types. For example:

```
let var1: number | string;
var1 = 'hello';
let var2: number = var1;
```

Now, the above code will properly throw an error that you cannot assign a possibly string typed `var1` to `var2`.

Comment: Hmm thanks @Behrooz, my issue is actually not as simple as the case I put, I just simplified it. I am using a library (AngularJs ui-router, but this is not that important) . Basically I am injecting an object of type `$stateService` and this object has properties of type any, and I can't control that. Actually, I have via tslint the `no-any` rule, so in reality my code looks something like `let var2: number = $state.params.thePropOfTypeAnyWhichICantControl;`
`. In any case, seems that I just can't do much about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) eslint rule to enforce [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) type everywhere instead of `any`:

<sub>.eslintrc.json</sub>

```json
{
...
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["error", {
      "fixToUnknown": true
    }],
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is a good but limited idea. The main problem I think is that many functions returns `any` (ie: JSON.parse) and is a good idea to have some way to avoid `var x:number = JSON.parse(str)`